# Mopub adapter for AdMob mediation

Tags: android, admob, ads, mopub

i'm trying to migrate from Mopub to AdMob mediation, but I can't find any custom adapters for Mediation to implement Mopub.

Has anyone tried to make an adapter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but creating an Admob CustomEvent to adapt between the Admob mediation framework and No pun should be trivial.